# std::find does not compile with custom iterator

Tags: c++, c++17

I found an [experimental circular buffer implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208293/ring-buffer-implementation-in-c14) with an iterator that looks like this:

```
    struct my_iterator
    {
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = long long;
        using reference = typename std::conditional_t< isconst, T const &, T & >;
        using pointer = typename std::conditional_t< isconst, T const *, T * >;
        using vec_pointer = typename std::conditional_t<isconst, std::vector<T> const *, std::vector<T> *>;
        ...
        pointer operator->() { return &(operator *()); }

        my_iterator& operator++ ()
        {
            ++index;
            return *this;
        };
        my_iterator operator ++(int)
        {
            my_iterator iter = *this;
            ++index;
            return iter;
        }
        ...
    };
```

See [the full source code here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9Uk5tts1Drf70nDv).

The iterator has a bit strange implementation, but at least it works with range based loops. The only problem is that it does not compile with `std::find`:

```
ring<int> mybuf(10);

auto i = std::find(mybuf.begin(), mybuf.end(), 100);
```

GCC9 shows the following errors:

```
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = ring<int>::my_iterator<false>; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const int>]’:
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:3938:28:   required from ‘_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = ring<int>::my_iterator<false>; _Tp = int]’
/home/def/repos/Awl/Tests/RingTest.cpp:71:60:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:162:34: error: no matching function for call to ‘__iterator_category(ring<int>::my_iterator<false>&)’
162 |          std::__iterator_category(__first));
    |          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h:205:5: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Iter> constexpr typename std::iterator_traits<_Iterator>::iterator_category std::__iterator_category(const _Iter&)’
205 |     __iterator_category(const _Iter&)
```

it is something related to `iterator_category` but it is not clear what wrong with it.

**EDIT1:**

Full source code :

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

template <class T>
class ring
{
    using value_type = T;
    using reference = T & ;
    using const_reference = const T &;
    using size_type = size_t;
    using circularBuffer = std::vector<value_type>;

    circularBuffer m_array;
    size_type m_head;
    size_type m_tail;
    size_type m_contents_size;
    size_type m_array_size;

    template <bool isconst> struct my_iterator;

public:

    ring(size_type size) :
        m_array(size),
        m_array_size(size),
        m_head(1),
        m_tail(0),
        m_contents_size(0)
    {
        assert(m_array_size > 1 && "size must be greater than 1");
    }
    
    ring(std::initializer_list<T> l) :
        m_array(l),
        m_array_size(l.size()),
        m_head(0),
        m_tail(l.size() - 1),
        m_contents_size(l.size())
    {
        assert(m_array_size > 1 && "size must be greater than 1");
    }

    reference front() { return m_array[m_head]; }
    reference top() { return front(); }
    reference back() { return m_array[m_tail]; }
    const_reference front() const { return m_array[m_head]; }
    const_reference back() const { return m_array[m_tail]; }
    void clear();
    void push_back(const value_type &item);
    void push(const value_type &item) { push_back(item); }
    void pop_front() { increment_head(); }
    void pop() { pop_front(); }
    size_type size() const { return m_contents_size; }
    size_type capacity() const { return m_array_size; }
    bool empty() const;
    bool full() const;

    size_type max_size() const { return size_type(-1) / sizeof(value_type); }
    reference operator[](size_type index);
    const_reference operator[](size_type index) const;
    reference at(size_type index);
    const_reference at(size_type index) const;

    using iterator = my_iterator<false>;
    using const_iterator = my_iterator<true>;
    iterator begin();
    const_iterator begin() const;
    const_iterator cbegin() const;
    iterator rbegin();
    const_iterator rbegin() const;
    iterator end();
    const_iterator end() const;
    const_iterator cend() const;
    iterator rend();
    const_iterator rend() const;

private:
    
    void increment_tail();
    void increment_head();

    template <bool isconst = false>
    struct my_iterator
    {
        using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = long long;
        using reference = typename std::conditional_t< isconst, T const &, T & >;
        using pointer = typename std::conditional_t< isconst, T const *, T * >;
        using vec_pointer = typename std::conditional_t<isconst, std::vector<T> const *, std::vector<T> *>;
    private:
        vec_pointer ptrToBuffer;
        size_type offset;
        size_type index;
        bool reverse;

        bool comparable(const my_iterator & other) {
            return (reverse == other.reverse);
        }

    public:
        my_iterator() : ptrToBuffer(nullptr), offset(0), index(0), reverse(false) {}  //
        my_iterator(const ring<T>::my_iterator<false>& i) :
            ptrToBuffer(i.ptrToBuffer),
            offset(i.offset),
            index(i.index),
            reverse(i.reverse) {}
        reference operator*() {
            if (reverse)
                return (*ptrToBuffer)[(ptrToBuffer->size() + offset - index) % (ptrToBuffer->size())];
            return (*ptrToBuffer)[(offset + index) % (ptrToBuffer->size())];
        }
        reference operator[](size_type index) {
            my_iterator iter = *this;
            iter.index += index;
            return *iter;
        }
        pointer operator->() { return &(operator *()); }

        my_iterator& operator++ ()
        {
            ++index;
            return *this;
        };
        my_iterator operator ++(int)
        {
            my_iterator iter = *this;
            ++index;
            return iter;
        }
        my_iterator& operator --()
        {
            --index;
            return *this;
        }
        my_iterator operator --(int) {
            my_iterator iter = *this;
            --index;
            return iter;
        }
        friend my_iterator operator+(my_iterator lhs, int rhs) {
            lhs.index += rhs;
            return lhs;
        }
        friend my_iterator operator+(int lhs, my_iterator rhs) {
            rhs.index += lhs;
            return rhs;
        }
        my_iterator& operator+=(int n) {
            index += n;
            return *this;
        }
        friend my_iterator operator-(my_iterator lhs, int rhs) {
            lhs.index -= rhs;
            return lhs;
        }
        friend difference_type operator-(const my_iterator& lhs, const my_iterator& rhs) {
            lhs.index -= rhs;
            return lhs.index - rhs.index;
        }
        my_iterator& operator-=(int n) {
            index -= n;
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator==(const my_iterator &other)
        {
            if (comparable(other))
                return (index + offset == other.index + other.offset);
            return false;
        }
        bool operator!=(const my_iterator &other)
        {
            if (comparable(other)) return !this->operator==(other);
            return true;
        }
        bool operator<(const my_iterator &other)
        {
            if (comparable(other))
                return (index + offset < other.index + other.offset);
            return false;
        }
        bool operator<=(const my_iterator &other)
        {
            if (comparable(other))
                return (index + offset <= other.index + other.offset);
            return false;
        }
        bool operator >(const my_iterator &other)
        {
            if (comparable(other)) return !this->operator<=(other);
            return false;
        }
        bool operator>=(const my_iterator &other)
        {
            if (comparable(other)) return !this->operator<(other);
            return false;
        }
        friend class ring<T>;
    };
};

template<class T>
void ring<T>::push_back(const value_type & item)
{
    increment_tail();
    if (m_contents_size > m_array_size) increment_head(); // > full, == comma
    m_array[m_tail] = item;
}

template<class T>
void ring<T>::clear()
{
    m_head = 1;
    m_tail = m_contents_size = 0;
}

template<class T>
bool ring<T>::empty() const
{
    if (m_contents_size == 0) return true;
    return false;
}

template<class T>
inline bool ring<T>::full() const
{
    if (m_contents_size == m_array_size) return true;
    return false;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_reference ring<T>::operator[](size_type index) const
{
    index += m_head;
    index %= m_array_size;
    return m_array[index];
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::reference ring<T>::operator[](size_type index)
{
    const ring<T>& constMe = *this;
    return const_cast<reference>(constMe.operator[](index));
    //  return const_cast<reference>(static_cast<const ring<T>&>(*this)[index]);
}
//*/

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::reference ring<T>::at(size_type index)
{
    if (index < m_contents_size) return this->operator[](index);
    throw std::out_of_range("index too large");
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_reference ring<T>::at(size_type index) const
{
    if (index < m_contents_size) return this->operator[](index);
    throw std::out_of_range("index too large");
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::iterator ring<T>::begin()
{
    iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_head;
    iter.index = 0;
    iter.reverse = false;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_iterator ring<T>::begin() const
{
    const_iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_head;
    iter.index = 0;
    iter.reverse = false;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_iterator ring<T>::cbegin() const
{
    const_iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_head;
    iter.index = 0;
    iter.reverse = false;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::iterator ring<T>::rbegin()
{
    iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_tail;
    iter.index = 0;
    iter.reverse = true;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_iterator ring<T>::rbegin() const
{
    const_iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_tail;
    iter.index = 0;
    iter.reverse = true;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::iterator ring<T>::end()
{
    iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_head;
    iter.index = m_contents_size;
    iter.reverse = false;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_iterator ring<T>::end() const
{
    const_iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_head;
    iter.index = m_contents_size;
    iter.reverse = false;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_iterator ring<T>::cend() const
{
    const_iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_head;
    iter.index = m_contents_size;
    iter.reverse = false;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::iterator ring<T>::rend()
{
    iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_tail;
    iter.index = m_contents_size;
    iter.reverse = true;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
typename ring<T>::const_iterator ring<T>::rend() const
{
    const_iterator iter;
    iter.ptrToBuffer = &m_array;
    iter.offset = m_tail;
    iter.index = m_contents_size;
    iter.reverse = true;
    return iter;
}

template<class T>
void ring<T>::increment_tail()
{
    ++m_tail;
    ++m_contents_size;
    if (m_tail == m_array_size) m_tail = 0;
}

template<class T>
void ring<T>::increment_head()
{
    if (m_contents_size == 0) return;
    ++m_head;
    --m_contents_size;
    if (m_head == m_array_size) m_head = 0;
}

int main()
{
    ring<int> mybuf(10);
    
    auto i = std::find(mybuf.begin(), mybuf.end(), 100);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin follow the link https://wandbox.org/permlink/9Uk5tts1Drf70nDv

Comment: It's not exactly rare for random code you find on the internet to not work. Did you go through all the problems mentioned in the accepted answers?

Comment: @Dmitriano That's against SO rules, I am afraid. If you want **free** help read the link, learn the rules and comply.

Comment: `my_iterator` is missing `value_type` member type. Once that is added, and a few other obvious bugs fixed, [the code compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/P6d68K)